# Why Navigation Graph IDs are not listed in R.id?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Android Navigation Component and I think I have everything ready for using it but when I try to navigate to another fragment using an action or a fragment id, the ids generated in the navigation graph xml file are not listed in R.id, so I can't use them to navigate.

This is the code I'm trying to execute:

`view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_addFragment)`

This is my nav_graph.xml file (autogenerated):

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
            app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">
    <fragment android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
              android:name="com.example.nopesal.costlist.MainFragment"
              android:label="MainFragment"
              tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main">
        <action android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_addFragment" app:destination="@id/addFragment"
                app:enterAnim="@anim/nav_default_enter_anim" app:exitAnim="@anim/nav_default_exit_anim"
                app:popEnterAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_enter_anim" app:popExitAnim="@anim/nav_default_pop_exit_anim"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment android:id="@+id/addFragment" android:name="com.example.nopesal.costlist.AddFragment"
              android:label="fragment_add" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_add"/>
</navigation>
```

As you can see, the ids are being generated with `@+id/` and it's supposed to appear in R.id when I try to referentiate them, but they are not showing. It doesn´t matter if I try to reference an action or a fragment, neither are showing.

I've tried to clean the project, rebuild, change the gradle navigation implementation, change the id names, restart Android Studio... I can´t solve it. Also searching for tutorials, using R.id is he only way to referenciate them so I don´t know what I'm doing wrong.

If anyone have faced the same issue o knows the solution I would be completely grateful.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just solved it!

I just noticed i had this imports at the beggining of the file. I suppose that they have imported automatically after copy and paste the navigation code. Deleting this imports fixed the issue.

```
import android.R.attr.data
import android.R
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use android featured modularization architecture, make sure import the right `.R`

Example:

```
com.example.feature_camera.R
com.example.feature_camera.R as cameraR
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,I have removed import android.R and it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).